# How to install wine32 in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, apt, wine

I'm faced with the following problem when I attempt to install wine32 on Debian 9.9:

```
# apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.7-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable the 32-bit architecture and install all necessary packages. See [the installation instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/Wine#Installation_on_Debian_Jessie_and_newer):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update
sudo apt install \
      wine \
      wine32 \
      wine64 \
      libwine \
      libwine:i386 \
      fonts-wine
```

Comment: Also works in Debian 10

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Debian 10 buster` and I had the same issue with `wine32`.
Seems the approach mention above was working since some update of Debian 10.9.
I resolve it that way:

```
$dpkg --print-architecture && dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
amd64
i386

$sudo apt remove wine && sudo apt purge wine
$sudo apt remove wine64 && sudo apt purge wine64

$wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
File ‘winehq.key’ already there; not retrieving.
$sudo apt-key add winehq.key
OK

$sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main'
$sudo apt update

$sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
$wine --version
wine-6.0

$sudo apt install winetricks wine32 

userdbn@debian:~/Downloads$ winecfg
wine: '/home/userdbn/.wine' is a 64-bit installation, it cannot be used with a 32-bit wineserver.

userdbn@debian:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install wine64
```

and after that all windows programs start working again.

Answer (score -1):

This is dockerfile which works for me (node, java, angular and electro)

```docker
FROM node:16.15.0

WORKDIR /work
COPY package.json .

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip

# node_modules witch angular and electron
RUN npm install -g n @angular/cli electron electron-builder

# JAVA
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless 

# Wine (Wine32)
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
RUN apt-key add winehq.key
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main'
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable

EXPOSE 3002
```